# Inheirit from a variable, Python?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I want to tell a class what to inherit from everytime I use it.

Here is an example

```
class widget(var):
    def __init__(self,var):
        #I really have no idea

bob=widget(wx.ComboBox) #I want the class to inheirit from wx.ComboBox
steve=widget(wx.ListBox) #I want the class to inheirit from wx.ComboBox
```

Please no questions like "Why would you want to do that?"

Comment: Why would you want to do that? (this was inevitable :) )

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the "decorator pattern", not inheritance.

Comment: Or a factory that sets some default values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope, this will help you:

```
class A:
    v = 'a'

class B:
    v = 'b'

def C(x):
    class C(x): pass
    return C
x = A
print C(x).v
```

**UPD Note:** Take a look at [python decorators](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators) if you haven't yet.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a *different* class each time that subclasses from whichever base class you want. You can do this easily with a function that creates the class on-the-fly:

```
def widget(var):
   class Widget(var):
       pass
   return Widget()
```